# Removing properties from JSON response

Tags: javascript

I have this JSON (as a string):

```
[{"product":{"id":"25","age":"35","name":"hp keyboard"},"quantity":1},
 {"product":{"id":"9","age":"25","name":"lenovo hero"},"quantity":2}]
```

How can delete or remove all `id` & `age` properties (with their value) from the array of objects, so I can get new array out of it?

Comment: That is not a valid Javascript array. Is that supposed to be in JSON format?

Comment: How did you get that? Did you manually type that? With a backslash here and there... quite randomly?

Comment: @steve, could you please have the courtesy to respond to the comments above?

Comment: In absence of a response, I have updated your question based on the comments below the answers. Please check that it is in line with your original intention.

Comment: yes its s JSON from localStorage like this  [
      "{\"product\": {\"id\":\"9\", \"age\":\"71\"\, \"name\":\"hp\"}, \"quantity\":1}",
      "{\"product\":{\"id\":\"5\", \"age\":\"71\"\, \"name\":\"lenovo"}, \"quantity\":1}"
    ]

Comment: Oh, but that is not JSON. That again is an array of JSON. It is confusing, since localStorage can only store strings, yet you specify an array, not a string. It would be good if you could provide some code **in** your question that allows us to run it and get such data stored in localStorage. Then there is no ambiguity.

Comment: its angular typescript shopping project, hence it has many service injected into it. So if i reproduce the codes, it might be too plenty for review......For instance, i posted an issue earlier on but a bit different in scope......because it was too plenty codes, no one  answer my questio... this is the url --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977072/how-can-i-upload-post-image-for-individual-dynamic-form-fields-in-angular-md  ....hence learning a lesson from that... thanks a lot for all efforts... i appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an array with two JSON strings, but as you present them in your question they are not valid.

I'll assume your array is in fact like this -- run the snippet to see how many backslashes really need to be there:

```js
let jsons = [
    JSON.stringify({ product: { id: "25", age:"35", name: "hp keyboard" }, quantity: 1 }),
    JSON.stringify({ product: { id: "9", age:"25", name: "lenovo hero" }, quantity: 2 })
];

console.log(jsons);
```

You should ask yourself why you stick with JSON, and do not just parse them, and then continue without JSON. But, given that you have JSON there, here is how you can remove the two said properties:

```js
let jsons = [
    JSON.stringify({ product: { id: "25", age:"35", name: "hp keyboard" }, quantity: 1 }),
    JSON.stringify({ product: { id: "9", age:"25", name: "lenovo hero" }, quantity: 2 })
];

let jsons2 = jsons.map(json => { 
    let { product: { id, age, ...restProduct }, ...rest } = JSON.parse(json);
    return JSON.stringify({ product: restProduct, ...rest });
});

console.log(jsons2);
```

Note how first the JSON is parsed, then a new object is created that lacks the two properties, and finally that is converted back to JSON again.

If you want to only keep some specific properties ("white list") in a flat (non-nested JSON, then proceed like this:

```js
let jsons = [
    JSON.stringify({ product: { id: "25", age:"35", name: "hp keyboard" }, quantity: 1 }),
    JSON.stringify({ product: { id: "9", age:"25", name: "lenovo hero" }, quantity: 2 })
];

let jsons2 = jsons.map(json => { 
    let { product: { id, age }, quantity } = JSON.parse(json);
    return JSON.stringify({ id, age, quantity });
});

console.log(jsons2);
```

In case your input is not an array (as hinted in your comments below), but a JSON string as a whole, then proceed as follows:

```js
let json = JSON.stringify([
    { product: { id: "25", age:"35", name: "hp keyboard" }, quantity: 1 },
    { product: { id: "9", age:"25", name: "lenovo hero" }, quantity: 2 }
]);

let json2 = JSON.stringify(
    JSON.parse(json).map(({ product: { id, age }, quantity }) => 
        ({ id, age, quantity })
    )
);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: *So i can get **new** array out of it*

Comment: @connexo, It is a new array, even if stored in the same variable. But hey, for you I'll use a different variable name ;-)

Comment: your solution was successful, thanks alot....but how can I add 'quantity': 1 & 'quantity': 2 to the product respectively............in short how can i generate a clean & simple array out of this old one

Comment: See addition to my answer. I would in fact also omit `JSON.stringify` unless you have a specific reason to stick with JSON.

Comment: the array of objects is a return data from a cart; hence this is the error i had in angular-typescript----- Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: But in your question you had presented the data as an array (see the opening and closing bracket there). Are you saying it is a string? If so, could you update the question to present the data as it really is?

Comment: I added another solution which expects the input to be completely JSON. If this is indeed how your input looks, please consider updating your question, specifying the input is not an array, but JSON.

Comment: how do I add a new key-value to the results....example : {gender: 'male'} to [{id: 6, age: 56, quantity: 4}, {id: 56, age: 89, quantity: 2}]

Comment: In the `map` part of the final solution, replace `({ id, age, quantity })` with `({ id, age, quantity, gender: "male" })`.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the array using `Array.prototype.forEach` and `delete` the unwanted properties:

```js
const arr = [{
    "product": {
      "id": "25",
      "age": "35",
      "name": "hp keyboard"
    },
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "product": {
      "id": "9",
      "age": 25,
      "name": "lenovo hero "
    },
    "quantity ": 2
  }
]

const newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)); // deep clone arr
newArr.forEach(function(arrEl) {
  delete arrEl.product.id;
  delete arrEl.product.age
});

console.log(arr); // old array unchanged
console.log(newArr); // new Array with deleted properties
```

Comment: thanks alot. How can I  add this key - value pair , 'quantity': 2 to the product object respectively.... example: "product" : {'id': '9', 'age': '25', 'quantity': 2}